# Dismissing a modalview while changing the selected index tab not functioning

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller

I have a tabBar application with a menu that is called up via a model view controller. Then when you select an option. I want it to dismiss while changing a SelectedIndex of the tabBAr.

here are my code snippets:

FirstTabBarController:

This is what calls the "menu"

```
-(IBAction)pressedButton {

    GWDNativeViewController *secondView = [[GWDNativeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [secondView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
    [self presentModalViewController:secondView animated:YES];
}
```

This is the code to dismiss within the GWDNativeViewController (Menu) view:

```
-(IBAction)dismissThisView {

    //Insert code to dismiss here
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [(UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController setSelectedIndex:3];

}
```

The line:

```
[(UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController setSelectedIndex:3];
```

doesn't seem to be doing the trick..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

appDelegate.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3;
```